# Uncaught Error Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/utils' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Anyone know a fix for this error?

Uncaught Error Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/utils' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\Dev\node_modules\ethers\package.json

Unsure what to change

Comment: Hi, I need a little more context. Could you tell me when this problem occurs

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I'll update you here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem sometimes happens with ethers version 6.x. The quick fix is to downgrade the ethers version to 5.x (I'm using "ethers": "^5.6.9" without any problem)